# How different is Elvis from Vim?

Tags: vim, vi, elvis

I've been using Slackware for a while now, which ships with [Elvis](http://elvis.vi-editor.org/) as its default editor.

Most other Linux distributions seem to ship with [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), instead of Elvis. Having gotten quite used to Elvis, will I face a learning curve when moving to a distro which uses vim?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of Elvis compared to Vim?

Comment: Why don't you just install `elvis`, then? Just because a distribution includes something doesn't mean you're forced to use it! Debian has it, for instance — `aptitude install elvis` will do it. By the way, ‘default editor’ is a variable, not a constant. Just set `EDITOR=/usr/bin/elvis` in your preferred shell's rc.

Comment: [O'Reilly's *Learning the vi Editor* has a free chapter on `vi` clones](http://oreilly.com/catalog/vi6/chapter/ch08.html) which compares – among others –  `vim` and `elvis` to plain old `vi`.

Comment: Elvis is dead. Vim continues to make progress and is currently being completely refactored as [*neo**vim***](https://github.com/neovim/neovim), which will greatly simplify the codebase and plugin architecture, and replace vimscript with Lua, amongst other improvements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Elvis](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/) and [Vim](http://vim.org/) are both highly capable `vi` clones, so your finger memory will serve you well when switching between them.

They share many `vi` extensions:

- Syntax highlighting
- Multiple undo and redo
- Visual mode, via <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd>
- Command history and completion
- Tag stacks (e.g. `:tags`, `:tn`, etc.)
- Multiwindow editing, via `:split`, <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>, etc.
- Extended regexes: alternation, subexpression grouping, etc.
- GUI version, in addition to the traditional full-screen terminal UI
- Remote file editing: read/write via FTP, and read-only via HTTP
- Removal of most classic `vi` limits, such as on line lengths and file sizes
- Improved programming support: `:make`, auto-jump to compiler errors, etc.

As impressive as Elvis is compared to stock Unix `vi`, Vim is even more capable:

- [Vimscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimscript) is much [more powerful](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#script) than Elvis' `ex`-derived scripting language.

  (Elvis and Vim extended the `ex` language in incompatible directions. This means you cannot easily port your `elvis.ini` file to `~/.vimrc` unless it's just a list of simple `ex` commands.)
- In addition to Vimscript, Vim can be scripted via Lua, Perl, Python, Racket, Ruby, and Tcl.

  (Your local Vim probably doesn't have all of these enabled, however.)
- The [Vim script archive](http://www.vim.org/scripts/) contains [thousands](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php) of Vim scripts, adding [highly useful](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) features, helper applications, [games](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=game&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search), and more.

  Elvis ships with just a few dozen scripts. There don't seem to be *any* archives of third-party Elvis scripts. (I tried Googling and only found scripts for [Elvis Presley movies](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Elvis_Presley_filmography). Sigh.)
- Vim 7.4 ships with syntax highlighting support for about 10× as many file formats and programming languages as Elvis 2.2 does.

  Their syntax definition file formats are incompatible, so you can't easily port between them.
- Vim 7.4 ships with 18 standard color schemes. If that's not enough choices for you, the [Vim Color Sampler Pack](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=625) is a curated collection of 177 top schemes, as of this writing. There are many more out there besides.

  Elvis 2.2 only ships with three color schemes, and that only if you count the GUI and [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) schemes separately. The [Elvis themes archive](ftp://ftp.cs.pdx.edu/pub/elvis/themes_archive/index.html) holds another dozen color schemes, total.
- Vim has a built-in [diff facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) with many improvements over command line `diff(1)` such as syntax coloring and merging.
- In addition to FTP and HTTP, Vim can also edit remote files via SCP, SFTP, WebDAV, RCP, and RSYNC.

The best reason to use Elvis over Vim today is that it's a lot smaller. The Elvis 2.2 footprint is about ⅕ that of Vim 7.4 on my system. This makes it a good choice for resource-constrained embedded systems, for example.

Elvis is a perfectly capable editor, within its limitations. But, while Elvis has been sitting stagnant for nearly a decade, Vim has continued to improve.

Answer (score 7):

As a VI clone, understandably, there don't appear to be many functional differences between elvis and vim. According to [Learning the vi Editor, 6th Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/vi6/chapter/ch08.html#ch08_08.htm), the only difference in is that elvis doesn't have incremental searching.

There's unlikely to be much of a learning curve moving from elvis to vim - they are after all both based on vi and at the very least share the same basic commands such as navigation, modes, search.

Most likely if you were to install vim and treat it as your primary editor for a day - you'd already know which features (if any) elvis offers that you'd miss, and any inconveniences vim might give you (if any).

I'm not that familiar with elvis, but some of the advantages of vim are the abundance of [plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php), and that it's maintained. The latest version of vim (7.3) was released in [2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29#Release_history), the latest version of elvis (2.2.0) was released in [2003](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/).

**Note:** as commented by alexios - changing distro doesn't mean you can't simply continue to use elvis.

Answer (score 4):

As a longstanding `elvis` user (since probably 1991), there is one `elvis` feature I'm missing with `vim`, the display modes.

It is very convenient with `elvis` to "wysiwyg" edit `html` and `troff` manual pages, and the split screen `hex` mode is also very useful.

Unfortunately, `elvis` is abandonware since 2004 and misses UTF-8 support which makes me most of the time using `vim` instead of it.

Comment: There's [a way to lash up a hex editor with stock Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_hex_editing). Or, as I do, use [`bvi`](http://bvi.sourceforge.net). For HTML, an editor-independent option is to set up [some kind of auto-reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588658/auto-reload-browser-when-i-save-changes-to-html-file-in-chrome) with a real browser. Elvis' understanding of HTML was imperfect a decade ago when it stopped moving. It's gotta be horribly outdated now.

Comment: @WarrenYoung No html text rendition can be perfect. `elvis` one is still convenient enough for most simple html documents.

Comment: Elvis is no longer abandonware, as of this writing the last commit is 11 days old: https://github.com/mbert/elvis