# How do you set up a "compiling parser"-like function to help with editing plain scripts in elvis?

Tags: vi, elvis

I'm using [`elvis`](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/elvisman/elvis.html) to edit files etc. in a context where limiting the keystrokes makes a difference<sup>1</sup>. I don't know all the implications of its [differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33745/44370) from `vim` and I'm actually inexperienced with both. I know [elvis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_%28text_editor%29) was *the pioneering vi clone, widely admired in the 1990s for its conciseness, and many features*.

A feature I really find useful in both editors is the [compiling](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/elvisman/elvisex.html#ERRLIST) options with the `make` command. But there is no such feature for scripts that I know of. Arguably scripts are smaller files and don't usually involve the same type of toolchain as compiling. Nevertheless, I ended up setting an alias (`ck`)in my `.elvisrc` file:

```
source $HOME/.exrc
:display syntax
:set number
alias ck {
! rm tempi
! (bash "%" >/dev/null) 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.*line \([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/p' >tempi
! elvis "%" +"$(cat tempi | head -n 1)"
}
```

This removes a *tempi* named file; executes the loaded script in `bash`;  searches for lines in the *stderr* output containing the word *line* followed by a space and some digits, and prints the number only; writes the number(s) to file; then we finally load our script again in another instance of `elvis` and go(`+`) to the first line # we pick up from the *tempi* file. It is not very elegant and requires the following workflow:

1. Open the script and run `:ck`
2. Another instance of `elvis` opens with the cursor on the line from the first error<sup>2</sup>
3. Edit and save/quit `:wq`, then press <kbd>enter</kbd> to go back to first instance of `elvis`
4. Repeat until there are no more errors, then **don't** save the top file, exit elvis `:q!`, then reload our - now corrected - file using *command history*.

Is there a better way to do something like this with `elvis` i.e. but without the many instances etc.?

---

<sup>1. A tablet with no external keyboard.</sup>

<sup>2. If there is no error the cursor goes to end of the file.</sup>

Comment: are you looking for something like `bash -n "%"` ?

Comment: it doesn't execute the script but does some syntax checking

Comment: @UlrichDangel I understand, thank you! I just don't see it doing anything on this platform (but it's quite exotic). I just added some random chars in front of a command and I get no echo with `bash -n`. In any case my alias "works" but I wish I could do without opening another instance and playing with a temp file etc...